# Only one checkbox checked in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a repeater with 1 checkbox for every item. I want to only have one checked at a time.

The checkboxes is asp:checkbox, don't know if it makes any difference.
I tried with some jquery but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ID="repeater1">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%# Eval("carousel_check")%>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

I have tried to give the checkbox a cssclass (checked_button) and then this script.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.checked_button').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.radio-similar').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: please take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We need to see some code. What condition determines if a checkbox should be checked? Remember when providing code, just provide enought to illustrate and replicate the problem.

Comment: I edited my question, hope this is more helpful :)

Comment: You may also want to consider using a radio button instead. From a UX perspective, users expect to be able to seelct more than one checkbox. Radio buttons also support the behaviour you're looking for without javascript intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net Checkbox is rendered inside span tag.

```
<span class="checked_button">
   <input id="MainContent_Repeater1_CheckBox1_2" 
     type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Repeater1$ctl02$CheckBox1">
</span>
```

So the selector should be `.checked_button input`. Then uncheck all checkboxes, and check only the one triggered the click event.

```
$(function() {
    $(".checked_button input").click(function () {
        $('.checked_button input').attr("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
     });
});
```

Comment: Maybe i seem to be a little stupid, but should i put the asp:checkbox inside the span tag?

Comment: Well, you just replace your script with mine.

Comment: Thank you. But i don't get what you mean with the click event. Can you explain more?

Comment: In jQuery, you want to use **click** event *(not change)* to catch check/uncheck event of checkbox.